# how can I catch the event minimize of the browser window in flash player?

Tags: actionscript-3, dom

This application is for a social network, so use JavaScript will not work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  And you can't in JavaScript, either.

You can react upon Event.DEACTIVATE ( when the Flash application loses focus ) or Event.MOUSE_LEAVE (when the mouse pointer leaves the Flash stage.  Maybe that will do the trick.

Comment: weltraumpirat, this only works if you resize the browser window, but I need minimize browser event.

Comment: Okay, we were obviously talking about two different things.  I changed my answer accordingly.